# android listview doinbackground can not show anything

Tags: java, android

I want to do a listview ,and I have lot of data want to insert it.
so I want to use doinbackground.
but when I use doinbackground,my listview never appera anymore,
how can I do ?
this is my code:

```
    public class Listening extends AppCompatActivity {
    ArrayList<Listenlist> listenlists = new ArrayList<Listenlist>();
    ListView listview;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listening);
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    }
    public void seraechsql2(){
        String result = dblisten.executeQuery();
        try{
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
            for(int i =0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) 
            {
                JSONObject jsonData = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);            
                track=jsonData.getString("track");
                Listenlist team = new Listenlist("T"+track+".mp3");
                listenlists.add(team);
                final ListenlistAdapter adapter = new ListenlistAdapter(this, R.layout.listenlist, listenlists);
                listview.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

        }
        catch(Exception e){}
    }
    class DownloadFileAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();        
        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... aurl) {
            seraechsql2();// it can not show listview...
            return null;
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {}
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String unused) {}
    }

}
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't update UI in `doInBackground` because it's background thread. It should be update in onPostExecute. Try this code:

```
 public class Listening extends AppCompatActivity {
    ArrayList<Listenlist> listenlists = new ArrayList<Listenlist>();
    ListView listview;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listening);
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    }
    public void seraechsql2(){
        String result = dblisten.executeQuery();
        try{
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
            for(int i =0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) 
            {
                JSONObject jsonData = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);            
                track=jsonData.getString("track");
                Listenlist team = new Listenlist("T"+track+".mp3");
                listenlists.add(team);
            }

        }
        catch(Exception e){}
    }
    class DownloadFileAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, ArrayList<Listenlist>> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();        
        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... aurl) {
            seraechsql2();
            return listenlists;
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {}
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Listenlist> result) {
            final ListenlistAdapter adapter = new ListenlistAdapter(this, R.layout.listenlist, result);
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
           for(int i =0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) 
            {
                // each time you create a new adapter and set it !!!
                Listenlist team = new Listenlist("T"+track+".mp3");
                listenlists.add(team);
                final ListenlistAdapter adapter = new ListenlistAdapter(this, R.layout.listenlist, listenlists);
                listview.setAdapter(adapter); // HERE!!!
            }
```

I think you should change like this

```
    public class Listening extends AppCompatActivity {
    ArrayList<Listenlist> listenlists = new ArrayList<Listenlist>();
    ListView listview;
    final ListenlistAdapter adapter = new ListenlistAdapter(this, R.layout.listenlist, listenlists); // initilize adapter
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listening);
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter); // only set once
    }
    public void seraechsql2(){
        String result = dblisten.executeQuery();
        try{
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
            for(int i =0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) 
            {
                JSONObject jsonData = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);            
                track=jsonData.getString("track");
                Listenlist team = new Listenlist("T"+track+".mp3");
                listenlists.add(team);
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();// notify listview that data has changed！
        }
        catch(Exception e){}
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to use doinbackground because I have a lot of data,i would leg if I dont use it....

Comment: Sure ,you can post a message to handler to notifydatasetchanged.